# ScrollViewer: Disable Snap (elastic band effect)

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a ScrollViewer on my MainPage that contains all other elements (except the AppBars of course). Scrolling works fine, but I want to disable the snap behavior (you drag the whole page to the left, release it and it will snap back). See the image (Background of ScrollViewer: Black, Background of Grid: White). So how can I disable this behavior? Also known as overscroll or bounce effect.

I just found out about *IsScrollInertiaEnabled*, but setting this to false doesn't help.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                  ZoomMode="Disabled" 
                  HorizontalSnapPointsType="None" 
                  VerticalSnapPointsType="None" 
                  ZoomSnapPointsType="None">
    <VisualStateManager>...</VisualStatemanager>
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Back button and page title -->
        ...
        <!-- My content grid -->

     </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry misunderstood what you meant.. Post some additional xaml if you can.. scrollviewer container xaml might help

try something like this

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    ...
    <!-- My content grid -->
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
      VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
        ZoomMode="Disabled" 
        HorizontalSnapPointsType="None" 
        VerticalSnapPointsType="None" 
        ZoomSnapPointsType="None">

        // put your content here directly or in a grid
    </ScrollViewer>
    <VisualStateManager>...</VisualStatemanager>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I meant. I don't refer to the visual states as snapped, filled and full. When my app is in full mode you can scroll the page as desired to see all the content. But you can still scroll a bit beyond the edge and then the full page will snap back. In the image above (simulator, touch mode) I dragged  the page to the right for example. Then at the left you see the encircled black space. The reale page and content of the ScrollViewer is the white area on the right hand side. Sorry, quite difficult to explain...

Comment: aaah you mean like the elastic band effect ? I need to try and replicate it,.. can you post some more xaml of how you are using it ?

Comment: Yes, exactly! That's what I meant. Please see my edit and thanks for your help :)

Comment: Many thanks for your edit, Hermit. But I'm afraid that doesn't help. Now instead of the whole page only the grid with my content has this elastic band effect. That's better, but the effect is still active.

Comment: unfortunately elastic band effect is inherent to the scrollviewer behaviour. try creating a xaml page with scrollviewer with additional controls that allow additional data view etc like flip view

Comment: Inside the grid are already other elements as several ListViews and also a FlipView. Or do I get you wrong? ScrollViewer.IsScrollInertiaEnabled isn't a solution as well.

Comment: have a look at the default grouped gridview sample (stock project template). does that exhibit the same behaviour ? if not follow its xaml structure

Comment: No, same behavior (gridview) :( I couldn't find one app on my device that didn't have such a bounce effect. So I guess I have to deal with it. At least for now. Anyway, many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem set height of the object inside the scroll viewer, let say.. if you have a stack panel, set the Height="2000" or else... and DONE. 
Note: Don't put any height in scroll viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I have other suggestion, i have faced similar problem, but i wanted to disable bounce, when only 1 element is in flipview.

So i did this:

Created a TemplatedControl:

CustomFlipView and it inherited from FlipView:

```
public sealed class CustomFlipView : FlipView
```

Next, i edited the FlipViewStyle to get the style code of FlipView ( yea, that big one ).

And copy-pasted into the Generic.xaml, into generated

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomFlipView">
```

So this gives me an opportunity to add names to such xaml controls, that by default are not named.

I have added a name to ItemsPresenter:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollingHost" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsTabStop="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}" VerticalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="Disabled">
    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="FlipViewItemsPresenter"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Next in the code of CustomFlipView i did this:

```
public sealed class CustomFlipView : FlipView //this line is indented.
{
    private ItemsPresenter itemsPresenter;

    public CustomFlipView()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomFlipView);
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        itemsPresenter = GetTemplateChild("FlipViewItemsPresenter") as ItemsPresenter;
        FixateItems();
    }

    protected override void OnItemsChanged(object e)
    {
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);
        FixateItems();
    }

    private void FixateItems()
    {
        if (itemsPresenter != null)
        {
            if (this.Items.Count < 2)
            {
                itemsPresenter.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.None;
            }
            else
            {
                itemsPresenter.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.System;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this could give you a hint.