# Flipview without rubber band effect at edge in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an app, which has 3 screens in first page as flipview items. Two screens has gridview & last screen contains camera. I want to develop nearly same UI as [6snap](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=82fa6341-28dc-4203-bd08-9749b167bc4b) from [Rudy Huyn](https://twitter.com/RudyHuyn).

In that it has camera in middle & two gridview (data view) at the ends. It doesn't have elastic band effect while swiping from one screen to another & it seems he has used flipview. I have chose flipview because it has selection change event & I can dispose camera resources efficiently. If my UI control choice is wrong let me know. I have tried to play manipulation events of flipviewitem but it doesn't work as expected. Any one out there who can guide me to develop the same flipview as 6snap.

[image]

Comment: Why not to use Pivot?

Answer (score 0):

Please check out my answer here:

[ScrollViewer: Disable Snap (elastic band effect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143931/scrollviewer-disable-snap-elastic-band-effect/29939523#29939523)

Maybe you will need to implement a different logic when to disable, and when to enable ManipulationMode, but it is possible